# How to post anonymous questions to SO?

Tags: support, privacy, anonymous

Can I just fill Name, Email, Home Page at the end of /questions/ask page?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Bobby: to ask 1) a potentially embarrassing questions without having to sign it to your name 2) to ask a controversial question 3) to better anonymize a problem if your company has a policy against asking on public websites for help, and I'm sure there are a lot more cases where doing this is necessary.

Comment: @Kop: 1. Questions are seldom embarrassing on SO. The only embarrassing part is if you proof to be learn-resistant in the course of answering/support. 2. "Controversial questions", ahm, that already sounds off-topic and like it doesn't belong on SO. Anyway, if you have a controversial on-topic question, feel free to ask it. 3. Ahhhhh...good point...I'll grant you that. ;)

Comment: Although not really a duplicate, it is the updated policy on this, so indeed voting to close. @gnat

Answer (score 7):

This isn't possible any more.

"You must be logged in to ask a question on Stack Overflow"

You'll need to create an account. The larger sites on Stack Exchange do not allow guests to post questions. There's more background on this decision and a list of the sites in this answer:

[Why are guests not allowed to post question but allowed to post answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227111/why-are-guests-not-allowed-to-post-question-but-allowed-to-post-answers/227114#227114)

Comment: I would clarify this is only the case on Stack Overflow, currently. (As far as I am aware, at least. A couple other of the larger sites might not as well.) Other sites do still allow anonymous questions.

Comment: The reason for this is people losing the cookie tying them to their questions, and all rights to do anything (e.g. edit) to them. So they end up 'answering' to comment, suggesting edits to their own stuff, sometimes voting on their own stuff and in some cases end up with _hundreds_ of unregistered accounts. The work this put primarily on moderators was just too much.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @404. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is how you would do it (after logging out, of course).

Comment: Remember to save the link to the question so you can find it again.

Answer (score -1):

You can click on your name on the top of the site to get to your profile. There, click edit and change the name to whatever you want. *You can only do this once every 30 days!*. The name you set here will automatically be displayed on *all* your questions and answers, including those posted before.

If you want to post questions/answers under a different name for whatever reason, you have to create another account.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question as stated. It should possibly be a comment, or removed altogether.

Comment: @tac This answer is over five years old, a lot has changed since, and back then I considered this this the only way to be "anonymous": Using a fake name in the user profile.

Comment: @DavidLively over a year later, i still don't think an answer deserves upvotes because it was correct when it was posted but is now out of date. (although this does seem a futile thing to argue over especially since i can't change my vote)

Comment: @cat sure, but it didn't deserve a downvote at the time, so I upvoted. A few months ago, I got a downvote on gamedev.se on a five year old, accepted, *correct* answer with +12 votes. It's annoying, and discourages participation which, in turn, damages the community. So, +1 from me.